# How can I install CUDA on Ubuntu 20.04 to a Dell XPS-15-9570 with GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile?

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I have a hard time installing CUDA on my Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti. I needed to install CUDA Toolkit 11.1 as it was recomended for Blender 2.92 here
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/CUDA

Comment: Would you mind doing an [edit] to the question to remove the solution, and posting that solution as an answer in the answer section below? Just helps us maintain the site format and I think gives other visitors a better chance of finding the answer they need

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which worked at the end of long work and I wanted to document it here.

I followed the instructions on:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

There it is specified you should use the kernels 5.4.0, however my kernels were 5.8.0 and when I followed the instructions it didn't worked out. I could install CUDA without any error messages but I couldn't use CUDA, for example in Blender.

You can find 5.4.0 kernels here
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4-rc8/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4-rc8/)

From the long list I took the amd64 generic kernels:
linux-headers-5.4.0-050400rc8_5.4.0-050400rc8.201911171930_all.deb
linux-headers-5.4.0-050400rc8-generic_5.4.0-050400rc8.201911171930_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-050400rc8-generic_5.4.0-050400rc8.201911171930_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.4.0-050400rc8-generic_5.4.0-050400rc8.201911171930_amd64.deb

When they are downloaded you can install them by running from the download folder:
'''$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local_11.2.1-460.32.03-1_amd64.deb'''

This page can help you more if you get stuck by reverting to previous kernel:
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-revert-to-previous-kernel/

Following them, I opened the grub with
'''$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub'''
and added this two lines:
'''GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true'''
and saved and updated grub with
'''$ sudo update-grub'''

To change the kernel version from 5.8.0 to 5.4.0 you need to enter to Advanced Settings on Grub screen. Grub is the black screen with a list of options appearing after bios, where you can also boot other operating systems. You can actually call it by keep pressing '''SHIFT''' or '''Esc''' However neither worked for me.

To see the grub screen at the start, I needed to edit the grub again and change this line:
'''GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden'''
to this
'''GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu'''
then save and update the grub file again of course.

Then change at the Advanced settings menu to the 5.4.0  kernel and now start with the installation instructions as https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html